# How to create a constant array of a custom class that exists throughout the whole application in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, class

I am new to C# and am trying to program a kind of card game. I have created a class that contains all the information that is unique to each card, and I want to create an array at runtime that will remain constant and be available for all the methods to use. Can I do this with a class, and if so, where do I create my array?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read up on static classes/ variables.

Comment: Static class was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 possible solutions here, all a bit different and with their advantages and disadvantages:

```
class Program
    {
        public static readonly int[] Info1 = new int[44];
        public static readonly List<string> Info2 = new List<string>();
        public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<int> Info3 = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new int[] { 1, 2 });
```

You can access InfoX via Program.InfoX, for example

Comment: To have anything like constant it should be the `public static readonly ReadOnlyCollection<int> Info3 = ...`

Comment: Thanks @SirRufo I forgot about that